# How to find the archive type of an iso file?

Tags: 20.04, iso, archive, compression, file-type

For my iso image I used the `tgz` format, but there can also be an iso with `xz`, `7z`, `tar` `zip`, etc. compression.
How do I know?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `file` command. It will list the actual. "test" is a text file and test2 a gzipped version where I removed the extension:

```
~$ file test*
test:  ASCII text
test2: gzip compressed data, was "test2", last modified: Sun Feb 13 11:00:17 2022, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 27
```

Comment: This method does not work for iso files. I just tried.